# Styling disabled inputs on tablet devices

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, browser, tablet

I am styling disabled inputs using the below css code. However **it does not work on mobile devices** (chrome and firefox).

`option:disabled{
  background-color: khaki;
  color:black;
}`

As you can see the below snippet works on PC but not on mobile devices.

```css
option:disabled{
  background-color: khaki!important;
  color:black;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option selected disabled>1</option>
  <option disabled>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
option[disabled="disabled"]{
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option disabled="disabled">3</option>
  <option>4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: the issue is on mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried resetting the native styling with the appearence rule? It's often the case on mobile devices.

```css
select {
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

Comment: Yes, still the same.

Comment: I meant to write `select` and not `option` (code updated). Did you try that as well?

Comment: Ok. Could you be a bit more specific about which mobile/tablet devices and which browser versions you are experiencing the issue with?

Answer (score 0):

```css
optgroup.disabled{
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <optgroup class="disabled" label="3"></optgroup>
  <option>4</option>
</select>
```